# How to get the ARN Value of IAM Role in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to run below AWS Cli to get the Role description but i want to filter this command to get ARN. I couldnt get the value but receive "null"

command :

can you provide the correct command to fetch the output of ARN Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Role` is a **json object**, not a list:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name cfnrole --query 'Role.[RoleName, Arn]' --output text
```